# R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) on Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Tags: r, rstudio

We're try to use the following in an RMarkdown file in RStudio, using RR version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) on Mac OS x 10.6.8:

````
```{r message=FALSE}
\library{UsingR}
```
````

When we knit to html, we get:

```
library(UsingR)
## Warning: package 'UsingR' was built under R version 3.2.2
## Warning: package 'HistData' was built under R version 3.2.3
## Warning: package 'Hmisc' was built under R version 3.2.3
## Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.2.3
```

We also tried:

````
```{r}
suppressMessages(library(UsingR))
```
````

And got the same error messages in our html output.

Any way we can suppress these messages? Are they harmful?

We cannot update our old laptops past 10.6.8.